# Complete mechanism of benzotriazole synthesis from o-phenylenediamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, amines, heterocyclic-compounds

Does my suggested mechanism for benzotriazole synthesis look correct? Are the arrows for the cyclization in the right place?

Chemdoodle (which I drew this with) makes the curly arrows look a bit weird.

[image: Proposed mechanism of benzotriazole synthesis]

Comment: Too many steps, amino could substitute H2O, then deprotonation.

Comment: You mean the intermediate with the pendant hydronium would cyclize with expulsion of water?

Comment: Your solution is plausible but I am bothered by the use of structure 7 the way you have. Its too far  to reach! If you do an electrocyclization of 7 to form the benzene ring and a 4-membered ring bearing vicinal nitrogens, then you can have the remaining nitrogen as a neutral "nitrene" ready for 1,2-shift of nitrogen and ring expansion. OTOH, acid-catalyzed cyclization of structure 2 followed by dehydration gets you there.

Comment: When I was drawing it I figured the electrocyclization through the electronegative N wouldn't work but ended up drawing it anyway. So I was right to be concerned.

Comment: The amino-to-diazo electrocyclization and 1,2 shift is interesting, but I think I like Mithoron's answer where structure 5's nitrogen displaces water and then deprotonates better.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Lzthh3G

Comment: Jacob, you are free to like what you like. I'm not convinced. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Species **1** is your seventh structure. The C=N=N atoms are linear and a long reach for the remaining nitrogen. Electrocyclization of **1** to **2** restores aromaticity. Nitrene species **3** allows for a 1,2-shift to an electron-deficient center with concommitant loss of strain in the 4-membered ring to produce 1H-benzo[d][1,2,3]triazole **4**.
Cyclization of **5** $\rightarrow$ **6** and dehydration via **7** gets the job done. Perhaps @Mithoron knows something that I am not aware of.

[image]